# ASP.NET equivalent of the java code

Tags: java, asp.net

Can anyone take time to convert this into ASP.NET?Please..

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    response.setHeader("Content-type", "text/calendar"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-length", String.valueOf(content.length())); 
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=event.ics");
    response.getOutputStream().write(content.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: This is lazy. What have you tried? The .NET equivalent is almost identical. What are you having difficulties with?

Comment: What language do you want? ASP.Net does not specify a language and can be used with any language that supports the CLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this out but it should look something like this...

```
public void DoGet(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{
    var content = request.Params["content"];
    response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
    response.AddHeader("Content-length", content.Length.ToString());
    response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=event.ics");
    response.Write(content);
}
```